# looping through json in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, json, oop

```
"obj" : {

"a" : [
      { "name" : "value" },
      { "name" : "value" },
      { "name" : "value }
     ],
"b" : [
      { "name" : "value" },
      { "name" : "value" },
      { "name" : "value" }
      ]
};
```

I have my json structured similarly to this in that "a" and "b" are objects that contain arrays which also contain objects.  I'm not very good with iteration/loops.  I mainly would like to get the value of "name".  any help? THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Be clearer pls...

Comment: convert the JSON to an object and then work with the object.

Comment: sorry. For example, say every "value" in "b" is a different number or a different string I'd like to be able to iterate/loop through and get each one in a single function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `forEach`:

```
Object.keys( json.obj ).forEach(function ( key ) {
    json.obj[ key ].forEach(function ( obj ) {
        // retrieve obj.name here
    });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/4Mrkp/

Answer (score 4):

```
var foo = JSON.parse(json);

for(var i in foo){
    for(var y = 0; y < foo[i].length; y++)
        alert(foo[i][y].name);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 0):

Using underscore.js ->

```
var obj = {

"a" : [
      { "name" : "value" },
      { "name" : "value" },
      { "name" : "value" }
     ],
"b" : [
      { "name" : "value" },
      { "name" : "value" },
      { "name" : "value" }
      ]
};

var names = _.chain(obj).values().flatten().pluck('name').value();
```

Comment: If you had a demo, you'd get +1 from me.